# What is wrong with my Pivot Table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot, pivot-table

I wants to display the row record of **TotalQtyParent** into column as a weeks

```
select 
    ItemLookupCode,
    StoreID,
    DepartmentID,
    Weeks,
    TotalQtyParent
from 
    #finalResult
where 
    ItemLookupCode = '610759C2000' 
order by StoreID
```

I tried SQL Query

```
select itemlookupcode, storeid, departmentid,[30],[31] from 
     (
        select 
            fr.itemlookupcode,
            fr.storeid,
            fr.departmentid,
            fr.totalqtyparent,
            fr.asofweekonhand,
            fr.weeks
        from 
            #finalresult fr
        Group By
            fr.itemlookupcode,
            fr.storeid,
            fr.departmentid,
            fr.totalqtyparent,
            fr.asofweekonhand,
            fr.weeks
    ) x

    pivot 
    (
        sum(totalqtyparent)
        for weeks in ([30],[31])
    ) p
```

But the output is some thing wrong and it shows the duplicate rows

I cannot figure out why it shows the duplicate rows.

Please explain with proper reason

Thanks

Comment: mostly, your problem is the `fr.asofweekonhand,` column in your subquery. remove it

Comment: As said `asofweekonhand` does not exists in your sample data, but there it is in the query. Running your query without it, and with your sample data - looks fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c3e0/1

Answer (score 2):

You do not require group by inside subquery, you can query as below:

```
select itemlookupcode, storeid, departmentid,[30],[31] from 
 (
    select 
        fr.itemlookupcode,
        fr.storeid,
        fr.departmentid,
        fr.totalqtyparent,
        --fr.asofweekonhand,
        fr.weeks
    from 
        #finalresult fr
) x
pivot 
(
    sum(totalqtyparent)
    for weeks in ([30],[31])
) p
```

Comment: thank you brother, I will accept your answer after 7 min.

Comment: Welcome... Happy coding

Comment: True that `group by` is not needed in the query, but it's not the problem. Query runs the same with or without it (even same execution plan). Problem is likely in commented comment that is missing from sample.

Comment: Yep you are correct, extra rows are due to the commented column, but my point here is group by is not required...

Answer (score 2):

As you may notice, a `PIVOT` performs aggregation. Simpler forms of aggregation in SQL are performed using the `GROUP BY` feature.

In a `PIVOT`, there is an *implicit* `GROUP BY`, covering all other columns currently in the result set.

So:

```
select itemlookupcode, storeid, departmentid,[30],[31] from 
 (
    select 
        fr.itemlookupcode,
        fr.storeid,
        fr.departmentid,
        fr.totalqtyparent,
        fr.asofweekonhand,
        fr.weeks
    from 
        #finalresult fr
    Group By
        fr.itemlookupcode,
        fr.storeid,
        fr.departmentid,
        fr.totalqtyparent,
        fr.asofweekonhand,
        fr.weeks
) x
---Point of pivot
pivot 
(
    sum(totalqtyparent)
    for weeks in ([30],[31])
) p
```

At the "point of pivot" I've marked above, the result set we're working with contains 6 columns - `itemlookupcode`, `storeid`, `departmentid`, `totalqtyparent`, `asofweekonhand` and `weeks`. The `PIVOT` uses `totalqtyparent` and `weeks`. This means that the other four columns act as if they're being `GROUP BY`ed - each *unique combination* of `itemlookupcode`, `storeid`, `departmentid` and `asofweekonhand` is going to produce one output row.

It doesn't matter that you don't mention `asofweekonhand` in the `SELECT` clause - the `PIVOT` is logically processed first, as part of the `FROM` clause.

So, if you don't want a column to be considered as part of this "implicit `GROUP BY`", you need to eliminate that column from the result set *before* introducing the `PIVOT` clause - either by not introducing it in the first place (as shown in [Kannan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600325/15498)) or by shifting your entire existing query into a subquery from which a smaller subset of columns can be `SELECT`ed.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation.