# How to make two pivot column with same column name using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I wants to make two pivot column using aggregate function with same column.

```
ItemLookupCode    StoreID    DepartmentID    Weeks        QtySold   AsOfWeekOnHand
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
610759C2000        1001        23             30             0         1.5
610759C2000        1001        23             31             0          0
610759C2000        1004        23             30             0          2
610759C2000        1004        23             31             0         3.5 
610759C2000        1201        23             30           0.6395       1
610759C2000        1201        23             31           0.6395       2
```

I tried using the following query. But it's wrong. What is the correct way?

```
select itemlookupcode, storeid, departmentid,[30],[31] from 
(
    select 
        fr.itemlookupcode,
        fr.storeid,
        fr.departmentid,
        fr.asofweekonhand,
        fr.weeks,
        fr.QtySold
    from 
        #finalresult fr
) x
pivot 
(
    sum(QtySold)
    for weeks in ([30],[31])
) p1 
pivot 
(
    sum(asofweekonhand)
    for weeks in ([30],[31])
) p2
```

**Note**

> Can we specify the column name as

```
Week30Sold    Week31Sold    Week30AsOfWeekOnHand    Week31AsOfWeekOnHand
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does roughly what you want:

```
declare @t table (ItemLookupCode varchar(20), StoreID int, DepartmentID int, Weeks int,
                  QtySold decimal(10,4), AsOfWeekOnHand decimal(10,4))
insert into @t(ItemLookupCode,StoreID,DepartmentID,Weeks,QtySold,AsOfWeekOnHand) values
('610759C2000',1001,23,30,  0   ,1.5 ),
('610759C2000',1001,23,31,  0   , 0  ),
('610759C2000',1004,23,30,  0   , 2  ),
('610759C2000',1004,23,31,  0   ,3.5 ),
('610759C2000',1201,23,30,0.6395, 1  ),
('610759C2000',1201,23,31,0.6395, 2  )

select
    *
from
    (select ItemLookupCode,StoreID,DepartmentID,
      CONVERT(varchar(13),Weeks) + 'Qty' as Weeks,
      QtySold from @t) t1
    pivot (SUM(QtySold) for Weeks in ([30Qty],[31Qty])) p1
    cross apply
    (select CONVERT(varchar(13),Weeks) + 'AsOf' as Weeks,AsOfWeekOnHand
    from @t t2
    where t2.ItemLookupCode = p1.ItemLookupCode and
    t2.DepartmentID = p1.DepartmentID and
    t2.StoreID = p1.StoreID) t2
    pivot (SUM(AsOfWeekOnHand) for Weeks in ([30AsOf],[31AsOf])) p2
```

Results:

```
ItemLookupCode       StoreID     DepartmentID 30Qty      31Qty    30AsOf   31AsOf
-------------------- ----------- ------------ ---------- -------- -------- -------
610759C2000          1001        23           0.0000     0.0000   1.5000   0.0000
610759C2000          1004        23           0.0000     0.0000   2.0000   3.5000
610759C2000          1201        23           0.6395     0.6395   1.0000   2.0000
```

Of note:

- You cannot pivot twice using the same column(s) - after the pivot, the columns mentioned in the first part of the pivot clause no longer exist, having been replaced by the bracketed new column names.
- We have to do an `apply` rather than a `JOIN` to a subquery to avoid introducing *duplicate* columns (e.g. `ItemLookupCode` would appear twice in the result set if `t2` was a `join` to a subquery)
- I took the opportunity to rename the `Weeks` columns in the subqueries
- when we use the `APPLY` we have to use `p1` as the outer reference - a `PIVOT` produces a completely new result set that replaces any existing result set/aliases.
- As mentioned in [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606017/15498), a `PIVOT` effectively `GROUP BY`s all columns not mentioned in the `PIVOT` clause - so why aren't the columns produced by the first `PIVOT` a concern during the second pivot? Because we already know that each combination of `ItemLookupCode`, `StoreID` and `DepartmentID`, by themselves are unique, due to the first `PIVOT`.

Comment: can you suggest me to read more about pivot in any tutorial page to understand more about pivot?..